# How to reload Flask-based webpage after receiving data

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, flask

I have a simple web project which gets data from, processes it and needs to output result on the page. After the spider works, the data is written to sqlite, but not displayed on the page. How to refresh page after writing data in sqlite?

button

```
<button id="scrape" class="btn btn-success mr-2">Scrape</button>
```

js

```
$.post('/wellness', {'specialty': specialty, 'state': state, 'city': city}, (res) => { 
});
```

flask

```
@app.route('/<page_id>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def page(page_id):
file_html = f"{page_id}.html"
file_py = f"{page_id}.py"
file_db = f"{page_id}.db"

specialty = request.form.getlist('specialty[]')
state = request.form.getlist('state[]')
city = request.form.getlist('city[]')

settings = ''
with open('settings.json', 'r') as f:
    for line in f.read():
        settings += line

settings = json.loads(settings)
settings['specialty'] = specialty
settings['state'] = state
settings['city'] = city

with open('settings.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps(settings, indent=4))

process = subprocess.Popen('python e:/Python/sqlite/spiders/' + file_py, shell=True)
process.wait()

try:
    db = sqlite3.connect(file_db)  
    cursor = db.cursor()

    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM wellness ORDER BY id DESC')
    cards = cursor.fetchall()

    db.close()
    return render_template(file_html, cards = cards)
except:
    return render_template(file_html)
```

Comment: have you checked that cards variable have records or it is empty and render_template renders the {page_id}.html page?

Comment: Of course I checked

Answer (score 0):

Write the appropriate append/fill HTML code to the div where you want to show

```
(res) => {
 # Write append or fill here 
});
```

Example

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/update/",
    type: "POST",
    data: {"data": data},
    success: function(resp){
        $('div.stats').html(resp.data); # Filling the data in appropriate div
    }
});
```

You would have to do similar thing for your use case.

Comment: I create a template with the module Jinja. Using post I am passing on the arguments.

Comment: Can you clarify how '/wellness' will route to '/<page_id>'.

Comment: Make a different route for /wellness and update the settings.json in that.
Then after that on a refresh to /<page-id>  [GET] request you can see the change. Remove the [POST] in methods /<page-id>. Did I get it right?

Answer (score 0):

solution:

```
$.post('/wellness', {'specialty': specialty, 'state': state, 'city': city}, (res) => { 
  $(location).attr('href', 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/wellness')
});
```